# Can a Bank Of America Cashier's check be cashed in another country?

Tags: bank-of-america, cashier-check, international-finance

I need to pay for a service in another country, can i create a bank of america cashier's check in the USA (in USD), send it to them and they can cash it like any normal check over there and it would show up in their account as their currency?

Is this different from a money order?

Comment: what currency is the invoice from the other country? I would suggest that they will be nonplussed to be underpaid on account of any currency conversion costs/fees at their end which they would deem your responsibility unless. of course, they have also invoiced you in USD equivalence.

Comment: TTD, requesting a doc from the gov and their instructions are "Send a money order equivalent to fifty TT dollars (TT$50.00) and the cost of return postage"

Comment: so Trinidad and Tobago Dollars. 50TTD equates to about 7.4 USD https://www.exchange-rates.org/converter/TTD/USD/50 I doubt that answers your question... Do you **have** to pay in USD or can you not use a fintech to pay TTD direct to their bank if you get their bank details? Might just be easier.